# Can't get partial to refresh when model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop down that is populated witht eh following code:

```
<span class="bluedept">Department:</span>
            <select class="selectpicker deptpicker" selectpicker ng-model="department" ng-controller="CaseListCtrl" ng-change="getCalendar();">
                <option ng-repeat="department in departments track by $index">{{department.CourtRoom}}</option>
            </select>
```

I then have this in my controller:

```
JBenchApp.controller('CaseListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
  function ($scope, $http) {
      // Case list stuff here

      $scope.getCalendar = function () {
          var e = document.getElementById("deptSelect");
          var department = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
          console.log(department);

          $http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/Calendar/LA/' + department + '/08-27-2015').success(function (response) {
              $scope.cases = response;
          });
      }

          $http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/CourtDept/LA').success(function (response) {
              $scope.departments = response;
          });


  }]);
```

The $scope.cases updates with new data, but the partial doesn't change to match that. What can I do to make the partial view refresh?

EDIT TO ADD PARTIAL VIEW CODE:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="$parent.loggedin">
    <div class="col-sm-12 calselectrow">
        <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar calicon"></span>

            <input type="text" id="calpick" ng-model="date" jdatepicker />
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar calclick"></i>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary flat-edge">>></a>

            <span class="bluedept">Department:</span>
            <select class="selectpicker deptpicker" id="deptSelect" selectpicker ng-model="department" ng-controller="CaseListCtrl" ng-change="getCalendar();">
                <option ng-repeat="department in departments track by $index">{{department.CourtRoom}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" ng-show="$parent.loggedin">
    <div ng-controller="CaseListCtrl">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 caselist" ng-repeat-start="case in cases track by $index">
            <div class="sequence">
                <input type=text class="seq-box" size="1" value="{{case.sequence}}" />
            </div>
            <div class="casetitle">
                <span class="caselink">{{case.Case_Number}}</span>
                <a href="calendar" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Calendar" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view" tooltip>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="documents/{{case.Case_Number}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Documents" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view" tooltip>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="parties/{{case.Case_Number}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Parties" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view" tooltip>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                </a>
                {{case.Case_Title}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 caselist-bottom">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="hearing-time">{{case.Sched_Time}}&nbsp;{{case.AmPm}}</div>
                <div class="hearing-title">{{case.Event}}</div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat-end></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please create a plunker ?

Comment: Well, I have managed to get this to grab the department, but now I cannot get it to refresh the partial view. I am about to edit my question for this issue.

Comment: code for partial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Try tracking the cases by their id or remove track by from the ng-repeat.</s>

<s>[ng-repeat not update model with track by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472079/ng-repeat-not-update-model-with-track-by)</s>

UPDATE:

I think the issue is that your are using ng-controller twice within your html causing a second scope to be created.  Wrap your html in a container div and apply the ng-controller attribute to that only.

Comment: I took the track by out and still doesn't refresh upon ng-change firing of the function

Comment: I have one area where the data loads based upon a default value pre-selected by the user. I then have a function that runs on ng-change. That function triggers, there is success, but the model doesn't update so the view won't refresh. As a test, I added $scope.cases = ''; in the success function and it still doesn't change the screen. Ideas?

Comment: Process...
1. Grabs default data and displays it...this works.
2. Change dropdown and have it trigger a function...that works
3. In function I am alerting a piece of data in the variable and it is correct.
4. In the function I am alerting a piece of data in the variable after it is updated and it comes up undefined

This means the data is changing, but the view is not updating. Any ideas here?

Comment: So it sounds like angular isn't aware that the cases model has changed, thus doesn't know that is should update view.  I would think that $http is 'inside' angular, but maybe not.  Try wrapping your model update in $scope.$apply() - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836007/ng-repeat-not-updating-the-list-when-adding-data

Comment: Actually that's probably not your problem, $apply shouldn't be neccessary, try wrapping your html in a container div and applying ng-controller only once to that.  I think using ng-controller twice with the same controller is creating a scope problem.

Comment: Tyler, you are a genius! Please add your response about the ng-controller as the answer to this issue. You fixed it for me!